# Any chance to get a superscript directly on top of subscript in Unicode?

Tags: unicode

Unicode [provides subscripts and superscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts), so I can do this:

x²

And this:

x₅

However, combining these two I get:

x²₅ or  x₅²

Which looks badly.

Any chance to get the superscript directly on top of the subscript in Unicode?

For clarity, this is what I'd like to achieve:

[image]

Comment: No. You need to use a math formatting program.

Comment: @DavidPostill Too bad :(

Comment: Out of interest what are you using the notation to mean? "x²₅ or x₅²" would ordinarily mean different things. Other than chemical elements I can't readily recall seeing that notation?

Comment: @pbhj It occurs often wherever people have reason to make up such a notation. For example the superscript if put in parenthesis could be the nth derivation and the subscript the mth part of a vector. Or whatever.

Comment: @pbhj My particular use case: x is a vector of unknowns in a system of linear equations. So we have: `a_1*x_1^5+b_1*x_1^4+...etc, etc`

Comment: @gaazkam: Complete sidenote: That’s a non-linear equation.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I was sleepy, I guess. `a`, `b`, ... are unknowns. `x`s are coefficients, like in Vandermone matrix.

Comment: I guess I'd want the subscript interior to the superscript for things like a_1.(x_1)^5.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your issue is not with Unicode but with the font you use. Technically, every font could use [negative kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) to move subsequent super- and subscripts on top of each other. One font that does this is Linux Libertine (if you put the subscript first):

[image: your example rendered with Linux Libertine]

On the other hand, this is quite rare. Even [STIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STIX_Fonts_project), which is specifically designed with mathematical typesetting in mind, does not have this feature.

Comment: Does it also work for x₅₅²²?

Comment: While I believe there are fonts which do this, it doesn’t seem like correct behavior.  The superscript and subscript characters are neither combining characters nor modifier characters, as far as I know.

Comment: @VGR: Well, from some point of view, you are not combining with or modifying another character this way. You just use space more efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Linux Libertine! — it works perfectly for writing music-theory analysis, e.g. "Ⅴ 6/5", with the 6 and 5 vertically aligned just to the right of the Roman numeral, as shown above with "x 2/5".