# Unicode : putting a superscript and subscript both on the same character, in a .txt file (not Latex, Word, or any other tool)

Tags: unicode

I'm writing text in an `UTF-8` file, and I would like to write about a combination of *k* elements among *n*.

I can write Cᴷ or Cₙ easily if I limit myself to a superscript or a subscript only, using unicode characters `u1d37` or `u2099`. But how can I put them togheter on the same character ?

Typing `C \u1d37 \u2099` leads me to an unperfect **Cᴷₙ** that isn't the look I would like my character to have. Superscript and subscript should be aligned vertically.

Comment: Any chance this would be a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1387577/any-chance-to-get-a-superscript-directly-on-top-of-subscript-in-unicode?

Comment: I fear it is, yes.